# For loop behavior

Tags: python, for-loop

This is strange.

```
a = range(10)

def remove_pop():
  global a
  a.pop()

for i in a:
  remove_pop()
  print i,

print '\n',a

0 1 2 3 4 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Why did the loop exit prematurely ? Shouldn't it quit only after `a` gets emptied ?

Comment: I think the problem is about you're using `for i in a`, try `for i in range(10)`. Now maybe you know what's wrong.

Comment: That should work,  yes. But what's wrong here ?

Comment: Let me post an answer and explain this :)

Comment: You are modifying the object you iterate over. What did you expect?

Comment: I expected the loop to run 10 iterations and empty `a` !

Answer (score 1):

The loop stops iterating once your index i is larger than the number of elements in your list. You popped 5 elements, so once both the list size and your index equal 5, it stops iterating

Comment: Shouldn't the index *refresh* eveytime too ? The index of each element changes each time since items are removed ; the index should be dynamically updated too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by saying the index should refresh. The index does change every iteration. By popping one element every iteration, the index reaches the end of the list sooner

Answer (score 0):

First, as I said in comment. Let's try to run your code:

```
a = range(10) # now, a is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].

...

for i in a:
    remove_pop()
```

Now, the first loop, `a` will become to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, and `for` is still keeping read `a`.

Let's see the loop:

1. `for` read the first element so `a` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, and `remove_pop()` will remove `9`, so the list **in this loop** looks like this now: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`. But the real list is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.
2. `for` read `1`, and `remove_pop()` remove `8`. Now the list looks like: `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. But the real list is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`.

....

5. `for` read `4`, and `remove_pop()` remove `5`. The list **in this loop** is empty now, and because `for` only read elements but it doesn't remove them, so `a` is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` now.

Comment: Feel free to downvote, but please add a comment to tell me what's wrong with my answer then I can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Initially a have {0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9} and then in each iteration you have remove one element as pop keep removing last element from list

see output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
0 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
1 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
2 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
3 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
4
```

At this time for loop index is equal to a size. so loop exit as there are no element to iterate.